# command to close the batch file in java

Tags: java

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec(command);
```

I am running the batch file by means of the above lines in java.
The command prompt will be opened.
I need to close the command prompt using java code

Thanks

Comment: Is the batch script hanging, or is it terminating and the window isn't closing?

Answer (score 3):

```
rt.exec("taskkill /IM cmd.exe");
```

or when you run your batch file

```
rt.exec("cmd /C batchfile.bat");
```

The second option is better in your situation. Less code, the command prompt exits once the batch is complete. The first option just kills an instance of cmd.exe open (which you may have multiple ones open).

to make sure it has finished running:

```
pr.waitFor();
```

-John

Comment: it is existing at the beginning itself

Answer (score 1):

Just update your batch (.bat) file with a new line and type in that new line "exit" (without the quotes). Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
pr.destroy();
```